# How to use Java Interfaces like this?

Tags: java, interface, bukkit

I'm working on a program and I want to use interfaces. Something like the way Bukkit used for their Player class, [here](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/d3ab9468c3aed2a06c280bf6c9cea5108c736dcc/src/main/java/org/bukkit/entity/Player.java#L27-L36). I've watched and read tutorials on interfaces multiple times and even tried testing by myself with no luck.

Let's say that I have a "User" interface, with a method placeholder that returns a string. The method will be named getName().

I want to do

```
User user = (INSTANTIATE SOMEHOW);
System.out.println(user.getName());
```

This is achieved in Bukkit's implementation much the same way

```
Player player = Server.getPlayer("Jimmothy");
System.out.println(player.getName());
```

I just can't figure out how to get something like that to work. In order to instantiate the player class, you use one of the many "getPlayer()" methods. The only problem is that the classes that contain those methods are also interfaces, so I have no idea how to get instances of the interfaces either. Searching through the code doesn't help either, because I can't seem to find where and if the methods in those classes were actually built using Overrides or something. (If that's how overrides work).

Who knows, maybe all I need to know is how to instantiate or get instances of the User interface and I'm all set. I know you can't create instances of interfaces using "new ClassName();" I've never really understood them, but I really want to.

This may seem like a really dumb question and I'm sure the answer is very simple, but help would be great! :) Thank you for reading.

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: An interface is nothing else than the assertion that a class has certaion methods/fields. Let's say you have a `class ActualUser implements User`, then you could write something like this: `User u = new ActualUser();`. It is just like a reference of a superclass referencing a subclass. You cannot create instances of the interface itself since an interface has no constructor. Interfaces in Java are (amongst other things) used to provide an alternative to multi-inheritance (which cannot be done in Java).

Comment: I think I understand now. So those "getPlayer()" methods are returning a class that implements the Player interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bukkit implements the `Server` in CraftBukkit (DMCA'd). The singleton is passed to `Bukkit`, which you can retrieve via the API using `Bukkit.getServer()`. However, you are interested in how the `Server#getPlayer(String)` method works.

In `CraftServer`, which concrete implements the `getPlayer(String)` method, it retrieves the player from the player's name. The players in the server is stored in a collection table with the name/UUID to the actual `Player` - which is implemented by `CraftPlayer`. Every time a player joins, a new `CraftPlayer` is instantiated and put into the collection.

So to do this yourself, you must implement both the interface for retrieval and the actual object to be retrieved. In essence:

```
interface Player {
    void kick(String message);
}

class CraftPlayer implements Player {
    @Override public void kick(String message) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

interface Server {
    Player getPlayer(String name);
}

class CraftServer implements Server {
    private final Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<>();

    public CraftServer() {
        Bukkit.setServer(this);
    }

    @Override public Player getPlayer(String name) {
         return players.get(name);
    }

    public void joinPlayer(String name) {
        Player p = new CraftPlayer();
        players.put(name, p);
    }
}

class Bukkit {
    private Server server;
    public void setServer(Server server) {
        if (server == null) this.server = server;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }
}

// Usage
new CraftServer();
Player p = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer("Name");
if (p == null) {
    // Not online
    System.out.println("No player with that name is online");
    return;
}
p.kick("lol");
```

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, you have found a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)! Let us jump straight to the code.

`Test.java`:

```
interface Player {
    String getName();
}

class PlayerImpl implements Player {
    public PlayerImpl(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private String name;
}

class Server {
    public static Player getPlayer(String name) {
        return new PlayerImpl(name);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player foo = Server.getPlayer("foo");
        System.out.println(foo.getName());
    }
}
```

As you see, the `Server` class has a `static` method returning an instance  of `UserImpl` as type `User`. That's the factory method.

This might seem (and, in this case, is) an unnecessary complication, but it has a key advantage: it decouples the use of a certain "concrete" class from the interface it implements. This allows for more flexibility:

1. It hides the implementation, so that you are free to switch between multiple different ones, as long as they all implement the `User` interface. From the outside, they all look the same.
2. It allows to implement pooling (every time you ask for a certain name, you are given the same instance) or any other allocation strategy.
3. It puts you in control of the object creation. You can perform, e.g., checks.

If a factory method is provided, then you should not instantiate an object  using `new`. If you *really* need to, you will have to look for an implementation of that interface. For instance, `PlayerImpl`:

```
Player foo = new PlayerImpl("foo");
```

Again, this is not how `PlayerImpl` is supposed to be used.

Comment: No it is *not* a factory method! That is because getting the player *does not* necessarily constitute a new instantiation.

Comment: Who said that a factory method has to return a new instance every time @xTrollxDudex? I even said the opposite in point 2 of the list.

Comment: "public static Player getPlayer(String name {         return new PlayerImpl(name); }" your example says otherwise

Comment: That's the simplest _example_ of a general case which is detailed in the discussion that follows. Again, point 2 of the list. And in either cases, it's still a factory method @xTrollxDudex. I can't really see the points of your comments... Not sure if trolling or serious...

Comment: "factory methods deal with the problem of creating objects". I am not trolling with a direct quote from your source. I recommend you to read the actual implementation code for yourself.........

Comment: Would you please stop making confusion between the general cases and specific instances and examples @xTrollxDudex? If you want to keep nitpicking, [here's a more authoritative source](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) that explicitely says _"Unlike a constructor, an existing object might be reused, instead of a new object created"_.  I don't doubt your code reuses objects, but that's absolutely irrelevant in the context of the answer and of factory methods.